# How can I fix a python error called "is not UTF-8 encoded"?

Tags: utf-8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpTBq.png)

I'm using Anaconda 3. Whenever I try to open a non-.py file (like .npy), I get this error in the image above.
Anyone know why?

Comment: Please: copy (usually you can copy paste from terminal) the errors. We do not check images. This site is not a forum, but a reference site, so the question should include all information and easy searcheable by internet search engines (images do not help).

Comment: [The `.npy` format is the standard **binary file format** in NumPy for persisting a single arbitrary NumPy array on disk](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).